# Finding changes between 2 huge arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

For the sake of simplicity, I have mapped a very large 2D space to a simple bit array (in reality it's around 200k of members).

Now let's say that I run a small algorithm that draws a "circle" of `1`s given a center point and radius.

Here's an example where on the left side a circle is drawn, and on the next calculation, it's center moved up by 1.

```
0000000        0001000
0001000        0011100
0011100    ->  0011100
0011100        0001000
0001000        0000000
0000000        0000000
```

Now I have many layers of these maps, and after I calculate them, I need to "flatten" them (sort of like Photoshop blending layer options) - and currently I iterate every time on the entire array and combine the entire arrays - even though 95% of them won't really change.

Psuedo code

```
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
   for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
      int index = x + y * width
      result[index] = layer1[index] * layer2[index]
```

This is highly inefficient and I need to improve my performance.

**UPDATE: What we ended up doing**

Sparse matrices was *exactly* what we needed, and we ended up using the **Dictionary of keys (DOK)** which best suited our use (dynamically building each layer and "blending" them together).

The solution we came up with was to use 3 arrays:

1. float array sized as the maximum number of members we might have (value)
2. bit array (same size), marking which member in the value array is valid
3. int array (same size), saving the indexes used in the value array (to iterate it later) + an incremental int which is used as a sort of a pointer to the amount of members in the index array

Since our needs were heavily reliant on memory usage and CPU, we wrapped each sparse matrix in a double buffer form, in order not to generate new arrays every blend.

Eventually this solution gave us around a x15-x20 better results CPU wise (than our previous naive brute force approach), and memory wise we lowered RAM usage by around 98%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, and using the photoshop layer analogy:

You have your underlying "image", stored as a "dense" 2D array, and of course since that's your data, every "pixel" is important. So far so good.

The extra layers represent *small* changes: When represented as a 2D array, *almost all* of its entries will be zeros.

In that case, you want to look into **sparse matrix representations**: Instead of storing a full 2D array, you just store a list of tuples `[(i1,j1), (i1, j2), ..., ]` that records the coordinates of the non-zero cells.

That way, any algorithm operating on these matrices will run on the order of how many non-zeros there are instead of based on how many total entries the matrix has.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply - I thought about it, but how do I know at what point does this solution becomes less efficient than the one I have at the moment?

Comment: Once your modification layers aren't "sparse" any more.

Comment: Another question, as I said my example was simplified - I store my data as a floating point number for each "pixel" - how would I store this sparse matrix? A dynamic list would obviously be very inefficinet. Would it look something like `PixelData[width * height] _sparseMatrix`?

Comment: For that I suggest you look up implementations of various sparse formats and pick one that best suits your application needs. It's a bit too much material to go into right now. There's things like coordinate formate where you store row, column and entry for each non-zero. Or there's compressed row storage, or compressed column storage, etc. They all have advantages and disadvantages, so you'll have to make it application-specific.

Comment: Reading it on Wikipedia right now, I'll try it tomorrow at the office. Thanks!